# Move an online domain to local computer

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, windows-server-2003, domain, tomcat

If I move a server to local machine, how can I access the website it's serving in my local network?

Right now if you go to the website's link, domain name will point to our server but what is we move the server from hosting company to our office. We don't need to keep the server accessible publicly. We just need it for local use.

Comment: Please mention your reason for downvote so I can review the question or delete it or move it to somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: This question is too broad - it would require an extensive tutorial to answer.  Describe what you've tried, and narrow your question(s) to specific tasks you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view a domain locally (not over the internet) you would need to add an entry in your hosts file with the following format

```
ipaddress hostname hostname2 hostname3
```

Example:

```
192.168.1.10 staging1.website.com staging2.website.com.au backend.website.com
```

---

Your host file can be found at either:

> /etc/hosts
>
> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Probably won't work too well when he moves his webserver from the hosting facility and what used to be at `www.whatever.com` is now on the office LAN and at `[Private IPv4 address]`, though.

Comment: I was thinking to ask it on SuperUser but I was confused. Anyway thanks for your help. Now I have a clue to what to look for at least. Appreciate your effort @VasiliSyrakis.

Comment: Just one question Mikael, when you say "local use" do you mean for multiple people to access on a LAN, or just local on the server itself?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis, doesn't really matter. Even on the server itself would be enough. We just want to browse the system as if it's online and build a new system based on that.

Comment: If that's the case, editing the hosts will suffice. If you need other workstations on your LAN to view it, you need to edit the hosts file on each workstation as well.